# Unable to see Maven Project option in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I installed Maven on Windows machine by following the instruction mentioned here: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

After installation, `mvn --version` returns expected result which shows maven has been installed successfully.

In order to create Maven project, I open eclipse and go to **File -> New -> Other**. This opens **'Select a wizard'** dialog but I didn't see `Maven` wizard for creating Maven project.

Is there any additional installation needs to be done, in order to create Maven project using eclipse?

Comment: Did you install maven from Eclipse marketplace? You have to install on your Eclipse also.You can follow this link: http://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/install-sect-marketplace.html

Comment: No, I didn't. Thanks! I'll do it right away.

Comment: I have added link on my first comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have installed is a standard maven setup which gives you command line interface (cli) of using maven. Which gives you option to use 'mvn' from your command line but to use maven from your eclipse you will need maven plugin known as M2Eclipse for eclipse.

You can find the M2Eclipse on [this](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) site just install it by going to eclipse Help > Install new software, once installed restart the eclipse and you will find New Maven Project in your new project wizard.